# Update user points on drag and drop JQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to update the user's points on each drop he successfully make, but for some reason the $.ajax call seems to not work as desired...
I am getting the current points using $('#userPoints').val(), then I would like to make each and addition to the current number or set first score - if...else. 
Any help?

function Point() {

```
            var phpPoints = $('#userPoints').val();
            if (phpPoints != null) {
                var Usrpoints = phpPoints + 5;
            } else {
                var Usrpoints = 5;
            }

                alert('Points: '+phpPoints);

            var sndData = { acts:'Points', points: Usrpoints    };
            $.ajax({ // begin add ajax
                type: "POST",
                url: "game/lib/updateGame.php",                 
                dataType:"html",
                 cache: false,
                data: sndData,
                success: function(sndData) {
                    $('div#UpdateUser').html(sndData).fadeIn('slow');
                }


              }); // end ajax

        }
```

Comment: i don't get it where is your problem exactly ?

Comment: For some reason it keeps grabbing the prev score which is 0, upon the first drop score is updated to 5 but from there on it doesn't 'pick up' that to grab the new score... am i missing something?

Comment: have you tried to set the score again inside the input `$('#userPoints').val(5);`

Comment: Was just thinking about that - i'm new to JQuery so still figuring it out. will try that or hack it someother way... thanks #Ninja's

Comment: let me know if its not working , another advice you have to define `var Usrpoints ` outside the update function then use only `Usrpoints`

Comment: Got is there's the fix:

function checkScore() {
    var phpPoints = $('#userPoints').attr('value');
    if (phpPoints > 0) {
     var Usrpoints =parseInt(phpPoints)+ 5;
    } else if(phpPoints == 0) {
     var Usrpoints = 5;
    }
    var score = Usrpoints;
    return  score;
   }
   function Point() { 
     //checkScore(); 
     var Usrpoints = checkScore(); 
   ...

Answer (score 0):

here instead of td use the element in which you are droping

$('td').bind('dropstop', function(){ Point();
});

Comment: Sorry am new to JQuery, that makes no sense...

what is $('td')?

Comment: you are draging the element to some div or td something like this